# Port forwarding prevents container from updating

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, port-forwarding, lxc

I use the following route on my host machine in order to pass all my traffic to a NGINX server running at port 8080.

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Unfortunately when I have that rule enabled all LXD containers (LXC for Ubuntu) cannot use:

```
apt-get update
```

since it resolves the repos as my domain.

Can I somehow prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting all the tcp/80 traffic with your rule.
In order to redirect only the traffic you want, you have to specify an interface or an ip address.
For example, you could use instead:

```
-A PREROUTING -i $MY_WAN_INTERFACE -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Or, if you need to redirect some of your LAN traffic aswell, you could write:

```
-A PREROUTING -d $MY_PUBLIC_IP -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
-A PREROUTING -d $MY_PRIVATE_IP -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```